# Joining multiple tables in MySQL via unique identifier

Tags: mysql, join

I have output stored in my database A and have seven tables in it (table1, table2, etc). Each table contains 30 output variables for a different block of a task the users did.

I am new to MySQL and want to JOIN these seven tables via their common "identifier" variable `UNIQUEID`.

I tried (for the first four as illustration):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2, table3, table4
WHERE table1.uniqueid = table2.uniqueid = table3.uniqueid = table4.uniqueid
SORT BY table1.uniqueid
```

This worked fine for two tables but not for three or more. Ideally I want that all seven tables are joined per `UNIQUEID`.

I am probably making a common mistake but the tutorials I found did not help me. Any help with a short explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `I have seven table` But you need just one.

Comment: I want to have them in one, yes. This is exactly where I struggle.

Comment: `t1.u = t2.u and t1.u = t3.u and t1.u = t4.u` and ... should works, but you need restructure your tables

Answer (score 2):

use explicit join syntax, you would do it like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.uniqueid = table2.uniqueid
JOIN table3
ON table2.uniqueid = table3.uniqueid
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If `uniqueId` is in all the tables, you can use:

```
select *
from table1 as t1
     inner join table2 as t2 on t1.uniqueId = t2.uniqueId
     inner join table3 as t3 on t1.uniqueId = t3.uniqueId
-- And so on
ORDER BY t1.uniqueId
```

(Notice that I'm using aliases to avoid writing the full name of the table)

Another option:

```
select t1.*, t2.* -- And so on
from table1 as t1
     inner join table2 as t2 using (uniqueId)
     inner join table3 as t3 using (uniqueId)
-- And so on
ORDER BY t1.uniqueId
```

Here, the `using` helps to avoid having to write `tx.uniqueId = ty.uniqueId` again and again

Also, notice that if you want to sort your data, you have to use `ORDER BY` (not `sort`)

---

I recommend you not to use `*` but explicitly select the fields you need from each table.

Also, check that your tables are properly indexed (at the very least, `uniqueId` has to be a primary key).